# Sorting an object?

Tags: javascript

How to sort this object lexicographically by its keys:

```
var obj = {'somekey_B' : 'itsvalue', 'somekey_A' : 'itsvalue');
```

so that it outputs like this:

```
for (k in obj) {
  alert(k + ' : ' + obj[k]); //first "somekey_A : itsvalue"; then "somekey_B : itsvalue"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The order in which `for..in` loops through the property names is implementation-specific and cannot be controlled. Your only alternative is to organize the properties yourself in some way, such as building an array of keys and then sorting it, e.g.:

```
var keys, index;

keys = [];
for (k in obj) {
    keys.push(k);
}
keys.sort();
for (index = 0; in dex < keys.length; ++index) {
  k = keys[index];
  alert(k + ' : ' + obj[k]); //first "somekey_A : itsvalue"; then "somekey_B : itsvalue"
}
```

You could, of course, put that in a function on the object and use it to iterate through the keys. Alternately, you could keep a sorted array on the object itself, provided you kept it up-to-date when you created new properties.

Comment: Sure. So I thought to have the object sorted before looping. But how to do it - that's the question.

Comment: I would just "sort" the array in PHP and be happy: sort($arr).

Comment: @dfjhdfjhdf: The point is that you can't, not ir you're looping via `for..in`. That behavior (loop in sorted order) simply isn't defined in the language.

Comment: No, not "loop in sorted order" but rather "loop a sorted thing".

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the keys of the object into a sortable data structure, sort it, and use that in your `for..in` loop to reference the values.

```
var ob = {
    foo: "foo",
    bar: "bar",
    baz: "baz"
};

var keys = [];
for (key in ob) {
    keys.push(key);
}

keys.sort();
keys.forEach(
    function (key) {
     alert(ob[key]);
    }
);
```

Comment: I would love to! What is that sortable data structure?

Comment: Any data structure that you can sort. I added an example.

Answer (score -1):

If the object is an arrya (or you made it an array using Prototype, jQuery, etc) you can use the native [array.sort() function](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml). You can even use your own callback function for sorting the values.

Comment: I haven't seen the ":" in the object. And don't worry, I don't blame you for my bad answer :)